# Language that uses IPA

Tags: ipa, list-of-languages

Is there a language that uses the *International Phonetic Alphabet* as their official writing system?
Basically,

1. Is there a language using [a less strict version of] IPA as their writing system?
2. Is that language a *natural* or *constructed* language?
3. How many people speak it?

Comment: English can be written using a subset of the IPA: the 26 letters of the basic Latin alphabet.

Comment: The IPA letters do have somewhat specific defined values for use in narrow phonetic transcription, but no writing system that I know of follows the principles of narrow transcription.

Comment: It would have to be a language without accents.

Comment: @sumelic That doesn't count in any way

Comment: @LuísHenrique IPA uses diacritics

Comment: @GamerGeek - I don't mean diacritics, I mean accents. English will not do, because someone in Northern England will pronounce "joostice" instead of "justice", so you wouldn't be able to have a unified IPA ortography. Portuguese won't do, because someone in Rio de Janeiro will say "treish" instead of "três". Etc, etc. I don't know of any language that has such an unified pronouciation that it can use IPA as its writing system.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know of any language that strictly meets these criteria, certainly not any major language, but there are some almost-but-not-quite cases:

- Many African languages use the [African reference alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_reference_alphabet), which is based on IPA (see jknappen's answer).
- Ad-hoc orthographies created by linguists when describing a language.
- The Journal of the IPA (then known as Le Maître Phonétique) used to be published using almost solely IPA (some proper nouns were written in standard orthography). Example:

[image]

Comment: WOW! Talk of dogfooding. Any idea why  Le Maître Phonétique stopped it? I googled a bit but didn't find anything.

Comment: @vin - since some English speakers pronounce some phonemes very differently from others, an IPA transliteration will necessarily be "wrong" for at least a subset of English speakers. It indeed surprises me that *Le Maître Phonétique* didn't realise it was a bad idea from starters; IPA is not meant to replace existing alphabets.

Comment: @LuísHenrique, I think your comment is very relevant to the OP's question, and would make a good answer, taking the stance: "your question misses the point of the IPA"...

Comment: @LuísHenrique I am able to write in broad transcription and have most people understand.

Answer (score 7):

No language (to my knowledge) uses pure IPA as its writing system. But there were orthographies devised for many Western African languages that heavily borrow IPA characters (like ŋ, ə, ɛ, ɔ, or ʃ). However, they have added the usual Capital/Lowercase distinction to their writing system, in this way deviating from IPA.

Answer (score 6):

The constructed language [Toki Pona](http://tokipona.net/tp/default.aspx) is [written with IPA symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toki_Pona#Writing_system). This is a phonemic transcription that doesn't account for allophonic variation, but still, the letters can always be read according to their IPA values. According to Wikipedia, the language has over 100 speakers. [Here](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/1706/591) is an estimate of relative differences of the number of speakers of several conlangs, including Toki Pona, based on LinkedIn profiles.

I haven't found any natural language that is written with IPA without exceptions, but there are a few that come pretty close, e.g. [Hawaiian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_alphabet).

Comment: That is quite intriguing, but both have a small phonemic library. 
Something with as many phonemes as english using IPA symbols could be interesting

Comment: @LingoLand I don't think such a language exists.